# Table Clobbered When Attempting Concurrent Writes - psycopg2.errors.SerializationFailure: could not serialize access due to concurrent update

Tags: python-3.x, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, concurrency

I have uncovered a potential issue when writing to PostgreSQl using a custom upsert function using SQLAlchemy.  In the event of concurrent writes one of the following errors are observed:

psycopg2.errors.SerializationFailure: could not serialize access due to concurrent update
psycopg2.errors.DeadlockDetected: deadlock detected

I have observed these errors by running multiple instances of a Python script via cronjobs.  Each instance of the script periodically attempts to write to the same table in a PostgreSQL database.  The script first shuffles the Pandas DataFrame being written so that each instance does not attempt to update the same row of the database table at the same time.  The results are disturbing in that the target table becomes clobbered with many of the original rows missing!  I have specified SERIALIZABLE to help guarantee consistency when concurrent database writes are issued.

Am running python3.10 with sqlalchemy 2.0.25

A notional code example follows.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert as insert_postgresql
_CACHE_SIZE = 5000

    def write(self):
        """
        """
        self.configure_data_for_write()
        
        self.configure_chunks_for_write()
        
        for self.chunk in self.data_chunks:
            self.upsert_postgresql()

    def configure_chunks_for_write(self):
        """
        """      
        self.data_chunks = \
            [self.data_flattened[i:i + _CACHE_SIZE] \
             for i in range(0, len(self.data_flattened), _CACHE_SIZE)]

    def configure_data_for_write(self):
        """
        """
        self.data_flattened = self.data.to_dict('records')

    def upsert_postgresql(self):
        """
        """
        session = Session(self.eng)
        # Set isolation level as strict as possible
        # to help ensure the operation does not
        # clobber the data!
        session.connection(execution_options={"isolation_level": "SERIALIZABLE"})

        try:
            # Get each record (row) from the current chunk.
            for record in self.chunk:
                # Build an initial statement to insert the current
                # record into the table.
                stmt = \
                    insert_postgresql(self.sqla_table).values(record)
                # Get portions of record who's columns
                # are not index column.  These will be
                # the values that get written to the table
                # during the call to :func:``~on_conflict_do_update``.
                update_val = \
                    {col: record[col] for col in self.col_all_minus}
                # Add to the statement to deal with cases
                # where there are conflicts ie: record exists
                # in table.
                stmt = \
                    stmt.on_conflict_do_update(index_elements=self.idx_label, \
                                               set_=update_val)
                session.execute(stmt)
            session.commit()

        except Exception as e:
            raise ValueError(e)

        finally:
            session.close()
```

Here are some mitigations that I am exploring to prevent my table from being clobbered:

1. Write (much) smaller chunks with each call to :func:`~upsert_postgresql`.
2. Have only one running instance of the Python script that writes to a given table.  This approach cannot be guaranteed.

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions on how to (1) confirm if a transaction of Instance A is being performed on a table at the same time as a transaction of instance B of a Python script and then (2) wait/retry the transaction of Instance A a number of times while the transaction from Instance B completes?  There are apparently listeners available from SQLAlchemy but will these detect transactions occurring from within another Python instance?  How can they be folded into the above code example?

Somewhat related: Why is SERIALIZABLE not preventing my table from being clobbered??  Rows just up and vanish!

Comment: I cannot understand your code, but the transaction isolation level does not prevent you from deleting rows in a table.

Comment: Thanks, although none of the transactions in my scenario involve deleting rows.  Should have clarified that I am attempting to update a reference table with time-stamps.  None of the rows in this reference table should be deleted (nor any new rows created) per this scenario.

Comment: You might try [setting the isolation level on the engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#setting-isolation-level-or-dbapi-autocommit-for-an-engine) to see if that helps.

Comment: If you choose serializable and you run multiple scripts I think a bunch of transactions are going to collide and fail and who knows what happens.  I guess probably tons of batches fail to commit at all.  You should be able to just use upsert without using the isolation level.

Comment: Thanks Ian and Gord, I think I have created a bit of a monster by potentially having concurrent cronjobs running.  Will try to space them out to help prevent database collisions, as well as setting the isolation level on the engine within each process.

Comment: @IanWilson If a transaction fail (no matter what the isolation level is), all its effects are undone. Nothing strange can ever happen: either all statements in a transaction succeed, or all fail and have no effect.